# Unable to delete content from a row in MySQL table in PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Here is my code:

```
$html = $_POST['html'];
$username   = $_POST['username'];
$saving     = $_POST['saving'];
$username   = $connection->real_escape_string($username);
$html       = $connection->real_escape_string($html);
$query      = $connection->query("SELECT * from members WHERE username ='$username'");
$matches    = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($matches == 1) {
   $row               = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
   $all_articles      = $row['readlater'];
   if($saving == true){
      $all_articles      .= $html.'§';
      $connection->query("UPDATE members SET readlater = '$all_articles' WHERE username ='$username'");
   } else {
      $all_articles      = str_replace($html.'§','',$all_articles);
      $connection->query("UPDATE members SET readlater = '$all_articles' WHERE username ='$username'");
   }
}
```

Here is the jQuery code:

```
if (localStorage.getItem(key) === null) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, 'Saved');
    $(this).css('color','#278F00');
    $(this).closest('.item').find('.fa-bookmark-o').css('font-weight','bold');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/savedarticle.php',
      data: {
        html: innerHTML,
        username: '<?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?>',
        saving: true        
    }
  }); 
}else {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
    $(this).css('color','#000');
    $(this).closest('.item').find('.fa-bookmark-o').css('font-weight','normal');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/savedarticle.php',
      data: {
        html: innerHTML,
        username: '<?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?>',
        saving: false       
      }
    }); 
}
```

I am HTML to a row with `§` as separator because this character won't occur in normal HTML. If an article is already in the row and user clicks on the unsave button I wanted to remove the article using `str_replace`, but it does not replace anything.

Also, when I click on the save button only once the article gets saved twice. I can probably work it out later.

**Edit: I guess the `$saving` variable always passes the value true. This also results in saving same article multiple times.**

I need help with the removal of unsaved article and also wanted to know if there is a better way to do this.

Here is sample HTML block:

```
<h2>Nexus 5X Receiving Update Today to Build MDB08I<small class="label droidlife">Droid Life</small><button type="button" class="close bkmrk-btn" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><i class="fa fa-bookmark-o" style="font-weight: normal;"></i></button></h2><p>Nexus 5X devices that are arriving at the homes of Android fans today are receiving a small 42MB update almost immediately out of the box. The build is arriving as&nbsp;MDB08I, which is a build first seen as a factory image earlier in the week.&nbsp; Tough to know whatâ€™s new in it, but itâ€™s likely...</p><p>Read More â€” <a data-id="1445529719-Unv5Og" data-toggle="modal" class="modal-link store-link" href="http://www.droid-life.com/2015/10/21/nexus-5x-receiving-update-today-to-build-mdb08i/" data-target="#myModal">Nexus 5X Receiving Update Today to Build MDB08I</a></p><hr>Â§
```

Comment: What happens when $matches > 1?

Comment: Why are you mixing `mysqli` OO and proceedural code?

Comment: @GordonM matches will never be more than one. All usernames are unique. And for now I have just one username in the table.

Comment: Is $saving set? also you have no closing brace here to close that statement. I guess it's just a copy error though

Comment: @Christian Yes, it is just a copy error and $saving is set. I am adding more code.

Comment: You are also not checking for and showing errors that may be occuring after any of the `query` executions

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: I didn't recognise it at first glance but I think your problem at its core is that you're violating the 1NF (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) and trying to shove non-atomic data into a single table column.  This is a classic mistake made by programmers who are still working in the flat file mindset.  Your problems can be resolved by storing the articles in a separate dependant table, one article per row, and using a foreign key to link the articles to a particular user.

Comment: @GordonM What is flat file mindset? How is it a problem? I mean what problems can I face with this approach of storing multiple articles in a single file. Thanks.

Comment: Sanjeet It just becomes unmanagable and prone to text manipulation errors. Also there is a limit to the size of a single row in mysql [See manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-restrictions.html)

Comment: @SanJeetSingh It's one of the most basic rules of good database design.  Every column in a table should hold one, and only one, piece of data.  That's what 1NF is all about.  If you need to hold multiple records for a particular entity (articles for a user in this case) then the correct approach is to use a dependant table for storing the articles.  Serialised data in a table column is always more trouble than it's worth and will always come back to bite you sooner or later.  Trust me, I've had to fix more than my fiar share of problems caused by this antipattern.

Comment: @GordonM Just one more question let's say there are 10000 users with about 50 saved articles each. That would mean 500k rows! Will it still be fast enough to select rows with a specific user?

Comment: @SanJeetSingh It would, if your design is well executed, probably be a lot faster.  The DB can use its indexes to quickly eliminate irrelevant rows when querying.  This is what I mean by "flat file mentality".  People who are new to relational databases tend to forget about the relational bit, which is what gives an RDBMS its power in the first place, and try to cram all the data they want to work with into a single table.  Don't be afraid to create tables and relationships between them.  In the worst case you can "denormalise" data that's causing performance problems later.

Answer (score 2):

You are approaching things wrong. Rather than storing all the articles in a single field separated by a magic character, you should have a separate table with a username and a text field. Then you can arbitrarily add and delete multiple rows to that table for each user. When you want to get all results for a user, you just do `SELECT * FROM new_table_name WHERE username = 'some_user_name'`.

Comment: You are **most definitely right** but as this is not an answer to the question it should have been a comment